# Install Composer on Azure web apps(Linux)

Tags: azure, drupal, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, cicd

I've made a website with **Drupal 10**, used Composer on my localhost. Then I migrated it to **client's server(Azure web app Linux)** using **Github action CI/CD**. The website works great.

Now We have new requirement where I have to install library. As we can not install library without composer.

I have to install composer on the production server but I can see composer folder already on the server.

How to install composer on the server?

If i install will composer folder be **overwrite**? will it **affect** on website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for composer get installed and work with PHP + Drupal and Github Actions, Make sure you add **`composer.json`** with your PHP version and then install composer if composer.json exists in the build stage of Github Actions workflow:-

My **`composer.json`**:-

```json
{
    "require": {
        "php": "8.2.14",
        "ext-json": "*"
    }
}
```

**My Github Action workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy PHP app to Azure Web App - siliconphp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.2'

      - name: Check if composer.json exists
        id: check_files
        uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v1
        with:
          files: 'composer.json'

      - name: Run composer install if composer.json exists
        if: steps.check_files.outputs.files_exists == 'true'
        run: composer validate --no-check-publish && composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: php-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: php-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_CAE11DA0DFBC4E8DB1AE0A113DDCC7EE }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_8F3D8711605B401D8FBC48CACF4E93F9 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_7DB451A63F4244D3AD08C4F85F84EFDD }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'siliconphp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
```

***Output:-***

[image]

You can install the composer manually by ssh'ing into the Web app like below:-

```bash
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SiddheshDesai for your reply! 
I have followed all your steps. But When I run the following commands
'composer' I get the following message
 'Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details Continue as root/super user [yes]'

Comment: Thanks, It's working. I switch from root to www-data to run the composer.